# Spark: Dimensions mismatch when merging with another summarizer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I want to study impact how additional training data helps the model performance (in terms of precision, recall etc.). I vary the sampling ratio as 0.35, 0.5, 0.75 and 1.0 (from 25% to 100% of all the data).

```
val sampling_ratio = 0.25
```

Read cases and controls from separate files.

```
val negative_training_data: RDD[LabeledPoint] = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(spark, "negative_sorted.tsv")
val positive_training_data:  RDD[LabeledPoint] = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(spark, "positive_sorted.tsv")
```

Taking a random subset (25% for now) of the dataset for both positive and negative entries.

```
val negative_split = negative_training_data.randomSplit(Array(sampling_ratio, (1 - sampling_ratio)), seed =  sample)(0)
val positive_split = positive_training_data.randomSplit(Array(sampling_ratio, (1 - sampling_ratio)), seed = sample)(0)
```

Here is where I combine the two splits to generate the training data.

```
 val training_data: RDD[LabeledPoint] = negative_split.union(positive_split)
```

Now train the LogisticRegression model.

```
 logrmodel = train_LogisticRegression_model(training)
```

Here is the code for model building.

```
  def train_LogisticRegression_model(training: RDD[LabeledPoint]): LogisticRegressionModel = {
    // Run training algorithm to build the model
    val numIterations = 100
    val model = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS().setNumClasses(2).run(training)
    return model

  }
```

However, I get the following error:

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkDriverExecutionException: Execution error
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:984)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1390)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Dimensions mismatch when merging with another summarizer. Expecting 4701 but got 4698.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:233)

Answer (score 0):

(You some some typos above and you haven't pasted the code of `train_LogisticRegression_model`.)

The error tells you you have different size vectors in positive and negative examples. You should check the size of the features as a sanity check on your inputs.

```
negative_training_data.take(3).map( _ .features.size).mkString("\n")
positive_training_data.take(3).map( _ .features.size).mkString("\n")
```

Comment: I have added the code for model building. The sizes are different First one is 4698 and the second one is 4789. How does this matter when you want to take their union and use it for training?

Comment: The number of observations, i.e. rows, can be different. The number of features, i.e. columns, must be the same,

Comment: I am merging two rdds:  val training_data: RDD[LabeledPoint] = negative_split.union(positive_split) and then I pass training_data to function that builds the model. Why should different number of features in positive and negative matter since for training  negative_split.union(positive_split) gets used.